# if an expression returns true/false, why can't I use it in a case?

Tags: ios, objective-c, switch-statement

I've already rewritten this with if/else, but its bothering me and hopefully someone can educate me. I've got the following switch statement:

```
  switch( true )
  {
     case [request.URL.absoluteString isEqualToString:secondMapUrl]:
        return NO;
        break;
     case [request.URL.absoluteString isEqualToString:mapUrl]:
        [self openMapViewController];
        return NO;
     default:
        return YES;
  }
```

Which fails with "Expression is not an integer constant expression" -- but those cases evaluate to true/false which you can use , ie. `case true:` -- is there a way to make a switch statement work in this manner?

Comment: The keyword: "constant"...

Comment: http://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-switch-case-statement has a good explanation of what of what H2CO3 means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler needs to be able to compile the result, where methods do not return constants (they are returning dynamic results which may be YES or may be NO).

"switch" is not appropriate in this situation.

And doing a "`switch( true )`" on a *keyword* (which is itself a constant and means certain things in certain languages that the  compiler supports), I don't even think that's valid. If you really have a variable named "`true`", you should change it to have a more sensible variable name.

Answer (score 0):

you cant compare strings like this with a switch you can only do constants such as  int/bool/char. with only two lines like that i would have done if else or if you have a lot of lines some form of a array and for loop to check. even if your switch was possible switch (true) would have to be changed to request.URL.absoluteString. the variable after the word switch is the thing being checked after the words case example would be

```
switch (my_Int) {
case 0: do something; break; 
case 1: do something else; break;
}
```